# Why is SharePoint creating a second image on top of the text in the nav bar?

Tags: top-link-bar, 2007

My top nav bar has a custom image that's 33x38 and my top nav bar is width:100 and height:38.  My custom image loads onto the bar fine, but the text area seems to create a second image under it.  This second image is the same as the first but just in a different location

Here is a picture of the problem:
http://img59.imageshack.us/i/probm.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the image is placed in too-high an element level in the top nav bar, and child elements within that element are replicating the image also.

Comment: I was able to fix it with some editing of both the custom css file I was using and the CORE.css file.  It was replicating the image like you said.

Comment: I'd advise against editing core.css as a best practice, as any service packs or updates will probably revert the changes you made. Override the relevant elements you need using your custom css.